# Xcode uses 16 gigs of RAM in 2 minutes

Tags: xcode, xcode4, xcode4.6, xcode4.6.3

I'm working on a big project and I have some serious problems with Xcode RAM management. In the informative app I'm working on I have over 90 `UIVIewController`s on my storyboard. Once I open my project and go to my storyboard file (just changing labels, zooming in and out etc') it takes less than 2 minutes for Xcode to go from 400MB usage to 8 gigs.
This will only happen while I'm using the storyboard.
This never happened to me in other apps I've managed so I believe it got something to do with the size of this app.
The above was on a new MacBook Pro. To test things out I tested it on a Mac Pro with 16 gigs of RAM. First run, same issue. 16 Gigs of ram is used after less than 2 minutes.

Things I've tried:

- Deleting DerivedData (the issue is on 2 different machines so it can't be it but tried it anyway)
- Deleting project.xcworkspace
- Read about stoping indexing BUT without autocomplete and quick help I'll have nothing to compile anyway

I'm using Xcode 4.6.3

Comment: Frankly, it sounds like a bug. Have you tried Xcode 5?

Comment: To my understanding I can't submit to the appstore with XCode 5 yet so there's really no reason for me to try it.

Comment: Indeed, you can't. However, if you try it and it's fixed, then you can pin it down as an Xcode bug rather than something you can do much about.

Comment: Bug or not, 90 view controllers in a storyboard is insane. Break it up into smaller files!

Answer (score 0):

sounds like it is a problem with that version of Xcode. I am using 4.6.3, and have never experienced this, (although the apps I work on are never that big). You should definitely try Xcode 5, even if you cant submit to the appstore, at least you'll be able to work on your app. Then you MIGHT be able to open it in version 4.6.3, and submit it from there, not quite sure it will work, but its worth a shot. Make sure you keep a copy of what you have so far incase your Xcode 5 version wont work in 4.6.3, so you dont loose your work. hope this helps.